# Ratchet head tracking with openCV and python

Tags: opencv, real-time, ratchet

I need to track ratchet head using opencv + python (raspberry-pi) in real time. Please refer to the images below.

I have been able to make certain progress there. But really unable to figure out a way to go for the complex shape along with shapes inside a complex shape (as there are circles and screws within).

I would need to also figure out the ratchet from sides but to begin with, I would like to seek support for figuring out the top view of the ratchet only.

Until now I have been able to detect circles in the image which was very straight-forward. I also tried template matching but that doesn't help in this case. I feel that if there is some way to detect the ratchet head by its outer shape and the big circle within, the job would be done.

Please note that the sizes of the ratchet heads will change but the shape roughly remains the same.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: industrial machine vision toolkits have "template matching" that works on contours and it is robust/invariant to rotation and scale as well. their algorithms aren't published too well. it's probably some variant of chamfer matching and (non-deformable) parts models, hence also a higher form of Hough transform (not the simple line/circle one). -- afaik opencv has no implementation equivalent or even comparable to what's available in those commercial packages.

Comment: within opencv, you could try feature matching and findHomography, since that head is roughly flat.